# File json exported by editor is not work

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

i import the obj file to editor and then export geometry to js file, when i put it on my code, nothing appear with the error in firefox debug:"Type Error: t1 is undefined" .
I change model to the .js file exported by MaxExporter with option "Export UVs", "Export Normals" selected, it's work fine.
Next, i change model to file exported by MaxExporter with only "Export UVs" selected, once again, "Type Error: t1 is undefined", so is this a bug or the problem is just my code, and how to fix it?

This is my code:

```
    var ambient = 0xffffff, diffuse = 0xffffff, specular = 0x000000, shininess = 100;

            var shader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "normalmap" ];
            var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( shader.uniforms );

            uniforms[ "tNormal" ].value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "md/normals.jpg" );
            uniforms[ "uNormalScale" ].value.set( 1.5, 1.5 );

            uniforms[ "tDiffuse" ].value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "md/diff.jpg" );

            uniforms[ "enableDiffuse" ].value = true;

            uniforms[ "uDiffuseColor" ].value.setHex( diffuse );
            uniforms[ "uSpecularColor" ].value.setHex( specular );
            uniforms[ "uAmbientColor" ].value.setHex( ambient );

            uniforms[ "uShininess" ].value = shininess;


            var parameters = { fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader, vertexShader: shader.vertexShader, uniforms: uniforms, lights: true };
            var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( parameters );


            loader = new THREE.JSONLoader( true );

            loader.load( "md/model.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, 100, material ) } );



            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );



window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}

 function createScene( geometry, scale, material ) {

            geometry.computeTangents();
            geometry.computeVertexNormals();
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            mesh.castShadow = true;
            mesh.receiveShadow = true;
            mesh.position.y = - 0;
            mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = scale;
            scene.add( mesh );

         }
```

Comment: Can you provide a live example?

Comment: Of course, here is the download link my project (r61), i haved make 3 html, code is extractly the same just different the model file.    (http://www.mediafire.com/download/etnkjld8pxqynao/Test%2520error.rar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your code.

`geometry.computeTangents()` requires vertex normals. You need to switch the order.

```
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
geometry.computeTangents();
```

That fixes the error.

But, `geometry.faces[4].normal` is zero. There is something wrong with your model.

three.js.r.63